# Figure Size & Position after Matplotlib Zoom

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython, zooming, magnification

I have a matplotlib image plot within a wxPython panel that I zoom in on using the native matplotlib toolbar zoom.

Having zoomed in I wish to know the size of the resulting image so that I can calculate the magnification.

Moreover, I wish to know the position/dimensions of my zoomed in image in relation to the original image so that I can re-plot it again at a later time.

I don't know how to approach this. I have looked over documentation for `canvas` and `figure` but haven't found anything which would help me pin point the data I require. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read the following from the matplotlib doc:

- [Event handling and picking](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)
- [Transformations tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)

However, especially the transformations tutorial may take a while to wrap your head around. The transformation system is very efficient and complete, but it may take you a while to figure out what especially it is you do need.

However in your case maybe the following code snippet could be sufficient:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(numpy.random.rand(10))

def ondraw(event):
    # print 'ondraw', event
    # these ax.limits can be stored and reused as-is for set_xlim/set_ylim later
    print ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', ondraw)

plt.show()
```

In the draw event you can get your axes limits, calculate a scaling and whatnot and can use it as-is later on to set the ax to the desired zoom level.